# Return a matrix that only contains samples with label 1 and that does not have negative values in the first feature python

Tags: python, numpy

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Um6Ru.png)

Hello, in the following image, I have this problem with numpy. I am trying to define a function like these

```
def preprocessing_matrix(samples, labels):
""" code """

    return
```

that returns a matrix that only contains samples with label 1 (of value 1) and that does not have negative values in the first feature (column).

Thank you in advance

Comment: 1. Please include all relevant information in your question, and include text as text instead of a screenshot. [Formating help](/help/formatting) is available if you need it. 2. This looks like a homework question. It's not okay to dump your homework here and ask others to do it for you. What did you try? What specific problem did you run into? Please read [ask], [what's on-topic](/help/on-topic), and the links therein

Answer (score 0):

You seem to want to drop any row with any negative element. You could create a mask then select the rows to remain (data1 is your original array):

```
mask1 = np.where(data1>=0.0, True, False).all(axis=1)

data2=data1[mask1]
```